# evitar registros duplicados en query y correccion de fecha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql

Tengo dos pequeños problemas con una consulta

1) Estoy realizando una búsqueda de los clientes relacionados a las bitácoras, dicho query debe de traerme aquellos registros de bitacoratiempo donde el código sea igual al id de los clientes, el problema es que no deberían de repetirse los clientes, si hay 3 registros de bitácora con el mismo cliente quiero que se solo se tome el primer registro, intente hacerlo con .distinct pero no me funciona de esa forma.

2)El siguiente error es que en la comparación entre fechas debido a que es un datetime si busco entre la fecha 2014-06-28 y la 2014-06-30 y existe un registro de la siguiente forma 2014-06-30 13:06:20 no lo tomara en cuenta en la consulta debido a que se encuentra en un rango mayor debido a la hora que posee. como podría solucionarlo?

```
  def self.total_clientes(params)
   query =  joins("left outer join clientes on bitacoratiempos.Codigo=clientes.IdCli")
                      .where("(bitacoratiempos.RutaId = :rutaId or :rutaId = '') AND (bitacoratiempos.IdEmpresa = :idempresa)",{rutaId: params[:search], idempresa: params[:search0]})
                      .distinct
  query = query.where('bitacoratiempos.HI between ? AND ?', (params[:search1].to_date).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), (params[:search2].to_date).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) if params[:search1].present? and params[:search2].present?
  query
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco el lenguaje pero para evitar eso puedes agregar a tu query

```
SELECT MIN(id_cliente) FROM bitacoras where id_cliente = 1 (por ejemplo)
```

El segundo error es facil de resolver, sumale un dia a la segunda fecha. De modo que si hasta (search2) es 2014-01-10 y le sumas uno va a quedar 2014-01-11 y tomara todas las horas hasta 2014-01-10 23:59

Comment: puedes usar la funcion find_by_sql y aplicar lo que dice @sioesi